# AWS JavaScript SDK Params - encoding/language/type

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I am trying to make use of the [getObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) SDK method to collect an XML file that is in a foreign language (Czech) and encoding (windows-1250) and convert it into UTF-8 (within a Lambda later)

Experimenting with setting the S3 Bucket File's encoding to match the XML Version:
    
is proving problematic, because the documentation is so limited. There are very few examples and I am struggling to find documentation to align what STRING_VALUE is eg. utf8 or UTF-8 etc.

Does anyone have Examples or a format for encoding/language to follow?

Thanks

- ResponseContentEncoding — (String) Sets the Content-Encoding header
  of the response.
- ResponseContentLanguage — (String) Sets the Content-Language header
  of the response.
- ResponseContentType — (String) Sets the Content-Type header of the
  response.

(Below is the example from the AWS SDK Docs)

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Key: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  IfMatch: 'STRING_VALUE',
  IfModifiedSince: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
  IfNoneMatch: 'STRING_VALUE',
  IfUnmodifiedSince: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
  Range: 'STRING_VALUE',
  RequestPayer: 'requester',
  ResponseCacheControl: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ResponseContentDisposition: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ResponseContentEncoding: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ResponseContentLanguage: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ResponseContentType: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ResponseExpires: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
  SSECustomerAlgorithm: 'STRING_VALUE',
  SSECustomerKey: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE',
  SSECustomerKeyMD5: 'STRING_VALUE',
  VersionId: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```